# How to create a world heat map in R - on continent level

Tags: r, heatmap

Im trying to create a heat map for country.txt file with table:

```
Region  Value
Europe  5
Africa  6
America 7
Asia    8
```

I know that i can view map as:

```
map.world <- map_data(map = "world")
mapCountryData(sPDF,nameColumnToPlot = 'continent')
```

How do i apply data to the map? I.e. i want the continent with highest value to be let's say green, the continetn with lowest value to be red.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simplified continents shapefile you can work with. I'd change the projection and remove antarctica for something I'd be putting into a publication, but this gives you a start:

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)
library(httr)

url <- "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hrbrmstr/91ea5cc9474286c72838/raw/f3fde312c9b816dff3994f39f2bcda03209eff8f/continents.json"
stop_for_status(GET(url, write_disk("continents.json")))
continents <- readOGR("continents.json", "OGRGeoJSON")
continents_map <- fortify(continents, region="CONTINENT")

data <- read.table(text="id  value
Europe  5
Africa  6
America 7
Asia    8", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=continents_map,
                    map=continents_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    color="black")
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=data,
                    map=continents_map,
                    aes(map_id=id, fill=value),
                    color="black")
gg <- gg + scale_fill_distiller("PuBu") # needs latest ggplot2
gg <- gg + coord_equal()
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
gg <- gg + theme(panel.border=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
gg
```

[image]

Here are the names of the continents as represented in the shapefile:

```
continents@data$CONTINENT
## [1] Asia          North America Europe        Africa        South America
## [6] Oceania       Australia     Antarctica
```

Comment: So your github link represents 'geographical map'  boundaries, is that right? Ok, it is something what i was looking for, how do i change the colors though? which part of the script is responsible for 'blues' as i cant figure it out...

Comment: `scale_fill_distiller("PuBu")`

Comment: I suppose its not the prettiest solution, but does the job in a way... wonder what other better options are there.

Comment: @BlueSkies So, as I said, it's a basic solution. You showed practically no effort in your question (not even the `library(rworldmap)` that is needed), and I have _many_ , _many_ other examples of geo styling in other SO posts, including how to change the projection and remove antarctica. With regard to the github link, yes. It's a shapefile in GeoJSON format (`help("readOGR")`), the underpinnings of most "geo stuff" in R.

Comment: Hi, this solution seems not working any more. If I add the `data` part, it will give nothing. If I did not add the `data`, it is fine. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @Zhiya I ran all the code in 3.4.1 with latest ggplot2  (et al) and it produced a similar result (`scale_fill_distiller()` behaves a bit diff but it all runs as-is)

Comment: @hrbrmstr Oh it is working now. I messed up with the json files. Thanks!